# splitting a class into smaller classes?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, adobe

I'm having this Idea to split my classes to smaller ones with specific tasks so I can use them  later more easily.

here is an example class to split:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class m4w extends MovieClip {
    public var upPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var downPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var lastMove:String;
    public static var spd:Number=6;
    public var ttt:MovieClip;


    public function m4w(stageRef:Stage, dtct:MovieClip) {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);
        stageRef.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed);
        stageRef.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed);
        ttt=dtct;

    }
    //Movement
    public function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey(event:Event){
        if (leftPressed){
            x -= spd;
            lastMove="left";
            detectPlayer();
            if(wlk.currentFrame < 18 || wlk.currentFrame > 24){
                wlk.gotoAndPlay(17);
            }
        }else
        if (rightPressed){
            x += spd;
            lastMove="right";
            detectPlayer();
            if(wlk.currentFrame < 26 || wlk.currentFrame > 31){
                wlk.gotoAndPlay(25);
            }
        }else
        if (upPressed){
            y -= spd;
            lastMove="up";
            detectPlayer();
            if(wlk.currentFrame < 10 || wlk.currentFrame > 16){
                wlk.gotoAndPlay(9);
            }
        }else
        if (downPressed){
            y += spd;
            lastMove="down";
            detectPlayer();
            if(wlk.currentFrame < 2 || wlk.currentFrame > 8){
                wlk.gotoAndPlay(1);
            }
        }
    }
    public function fl_SetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        switch (event.keyCode){
            case 87:
            case 38:{
                upPressed = true;
                break;
            }
            case 83:
            case 40:{
                downPressed = true;
                break;
            }
            case 65:
            case 37:{
                leftPressed = true;
                break;
            }
            case 68:
            case 39:{
                rightPressed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public function fl_UnsetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        switch (event.keyCode){
            case 87:
            case 38:{
                upPressed = false;
                break;
            }
            case 83:
            case 40:{
                downPressed = false;
                break;
            }
            case 65:
            case 37:{
                leftPressed = false;
                break;
            }
            case 68:
            case 39:{
                rightPressed = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //Movement
    public function detectPlayer(){
        if (ttt.hitTestPoint(x, y, true)){ 
            if( lastMove == "right"){
                x -= spd;
            }
            if( lastMove == "left"){
                x += spd;
            }
            if( lastMove == "up"){
                y += spd;
            }
            if( lastMove == "down"){
                y -= spd;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

It's a pawn class with 3 tasks movement/controlling movement graphics/collision detection.
now the question is how a pro would do this? or is it a good Idea at all?

and the additional question is when I split them into different classes whats the best way to add their functionalists into one class? I know that it's possible to make the classes extend of each other till the final class have all of properties but I don't think that's be best way.

thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example class is pretty tiny, straight forward, and logically inclusive. As far as reusability goes, you're really searching for flexibility which is handled with the class design and structure. So using the example class `m4w`, you might remove the `detectPlayer()` and put it in a parent class, I'll call it `Collidables`. You then might rename that function to be more generic, that would look something like:

```
class Collidables extends MovieClip {

    public function hitPointCollision( obj:DisplayObject, p:Point, callback:Function=null ):Boolean {
        if ( obj.hitTestPoint( p.x, p.y, true ) ) {
            if ( callback != null ) {
                callback();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is extremely basic, but provides any class inheriting from Collidables with a `hitPointCollision()` to use.

You might also move the listeners handling your controls to a separate class called a "Controller" that will decide what to do when specified keys are pressed. This is also the start of what's known as the MVC or Model View Controller design pattern which you can find here: [Design Patterns AS3.0 - MVC](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/ora_as3_design_patterns.html)

When you are looking at ways for your program to be flexible and extensible, you will benefit from taking a look at design patterns and how they are used to solve various problems. The aforementioned link has some details regarding design patterns, or take a look at GOF (Gang of Four) Design Patterns since that's where it all started: [Gang of Four: Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)

Comment: thanks for the tips I can see the points. but you should learn to not trow books at lazy people ^_^